# Combining Traefik frontend redirect replacement with PathPrefixStrip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am encountering some conflicts between the `traefik.frontend.redirect` and `PathPrefixStrip`. the `docker-compose.yml` file below always routes `www.mysite.nl/adminer` to the wordpress container. If I omit the redirect rules it works correctly and i get routed to the adminer instance. How can I make these rules work together?

Drilled down `docker-comose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest 
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_wp
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME'
      - 'traefik.entrypoint=https'
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mysite.nl, www.mysite.nl, cdn.mysite.net'
       # omitting these rules make the adminer instance reachable
      - 'traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://mysite.nl/(.*)'
      - 'traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://www.mysite.nl/$${1}'
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db
    networks:
      - web
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.6.2
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_adminer'
      - 'traefik.entrypoint=https'
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mysite.nl;PathPrefixStrip:/adminer'

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are running into is due to overlapping rules.

The request `www.mysite.nl/adminer`

Matches both:
`traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mysite.nl, www.mysite.nl, cdn.mysite.net`
and `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mysite.nl;PathPrefixStrip:/adminer`

Therefore Traefik does not know which to route requests to.

Use the `traefik.frontend.priority` label to set an order for matching (from https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers)

Comment: That makes perfectly sense! I have tried `- 'traefik.frontend.priority=9'
`  and 20 on the adminer container. after rebuilding i still end up on the wordpress container. Looking at the traefik dashboard i see that the priority is coming through. 

The adminer priority have to be higher right? What am I missing.

Comment: Yes. Higher priority = Matched first.
If you set `traefik.enabled=false` on the wordpress container, can you access the admin properly?

Comment: Just tried. When the Wordpress container is disabled like you said I can reach the Adminer container on www.mysite.com/adminer

Comment: I just added   - 'traefik.frontend.priority=20' to the Adminer instance and   - 'traefik.frontend.priority=5' to the Wordpress instance and it worked! Is that expected behavior? I thought the priority defaults to 10

Answer (score 2):

With help from Daniel Tomcej i came to the following working `docker-compose.yml`. You have to set the priority explicitly on both containers.

```
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest 
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_wp
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME'
      - 'traefik.entrypoint=https'
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mysite.nl, www.mysite.nl, cdn.mysite.net'
      - 'traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https?://mysite.nl/(.*)'
      - 'traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://www.mysite.nl/$${1}'
      - 'traefik.frontend.priority=5'
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db
    networks:
      - web
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.6.2
    restart: $RESTART
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - 'traefik.backend=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_adminer'
      - 'traefik.entrypoint=https'
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mysite.nl;PathPrefixStrip:/adminer'
      - 'traefik.frontend.priority=20'

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web
```